# React native app is installed but not opening after setting compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion to 31 (Android 12)

Tags: android, react-native, androidsdk31

I am developing a react native app for both android and iOS. I was using compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion as 30. But as form November, a minimum sdk version as 31 is required to upload the project to google play console.

So I have updated the SDK version as 31 and run the project in emulator. Which is working fine. Then I tried running the app in a android mobile which is using Android 12. The app is installing in the phone but when I try to open I am unable to do it. There is no error in the console or any error message while trying to open the app.

I have added implementation `'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-alpha05'` in my gradle file and also added `android:exported="true"` in the manifest file.

Also I check all the package I have whether it support sdk version 31. All of them are in correct place. But still I am unable to open the app.

I tried running in another android phone which is having android version less than 12 and I was able to run and open the app there.

Can anyone please tell me whether am I missing any configuration to run the app in Android 12.

Comment: I am using react-native version 63.3

Comment: I tried updating to 64.4 too. ut still same error. Please help. I will provide all the necessary details